# will this code result in successful creation of two child processes from parent processes?

Tags: c, fork

This is my C code for creating two child processes from a parent process.
Will this successfully create? My current output is:

> You are in parent process whose id is 29509
>      you are in child process 1 and your parent id is 29509
>      You are in parent process whose id is 29511
>      you are in child process 2 and your parent id is 29509

Why is that in the third line of my output the parent id is different??

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    int main(){
            pid_t child1,child2;
            int c,d,e;
            child1=fork();
            if(child1==0){
                    c=getppid();
                    printf("you are in child process 1 and your parent id is %d\n",c);

            }
            else{
                    child2=fork();
                    e=getpid();
                    printf("You are in parent process whose id is %d\n",e);
            }
            if(child2==0){
                    d=getppid();
                    printf("you are in child process 2 and your parent id is %d\n",d);
            }
    }
```

Output is

```
You are in parent process whose id is 29509
you are in child process 1 and your parent id is 29509
You are in parent process whose id is 29511
you are in child process 2 and your parent id is 29509
```

Answer (score 1):

After your second `fork`, both the parent and the second child execute the "parent process" `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

`e=getpid();
                    printf("You are in parent process whose id is %d\n",e);`

These lines are executed by the parent AND the child.